# How to embed blocks of data in ExpressionEngine without using many channels

Tags: expressionengine, channel

I have used Drupal and think I'm doing it wrong with EE. I want to create many blocks of embedded User created entries in some of the templates, but don't want to have to create a channel for each one. In Drupal I could create a block specific to the client's needs, but I'm stumped on how to do this in EE. 
For example, I have three different content areas on the home page, top/middle and bottom. Client doesn't want to roll out blog entries, they want specific content put in each one. The only way I see is I'd need to create three different channels and embed as such for top, changing channel to middle and bottom for each block. Is there a better way?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="top" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" limit="1"
sort="desc" dynamic="no" }
```

Would I use category group and categories to do this? Meaning, I would create top, middle and bottom categories to call out those entries in my "home" channel?

Comment: I created a category group and categories within that group. I then assigned entries in that channel to specific categories (top, middle, bottom). Then in the template, I use category id to pull only the content I want:    {exp:channel:entries category="1" channel="top" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" limit="1"
sort="desc" dynamic="no" }

Answer (score 1):

For less than 1 hour of billable work, you'll get hundreds if not thousands of hours of effort packaged up for you to run with. Someone always pays for code, why not you this time? :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have found does work - but I've found that ultimately it does not offer the flexibility needed by many clients.

I've used the following solution for many sites and clients have been pleased with it.

1) Define your block data as channels. For example I often have a Sidbar Ad, Sidebar Scripts, and Sidebar text channels.

2) Use a playa field-type (or another relational field-type) to create relationships from a parent entry (a page) to theses sub content types.

This normally looks something like this on the backend:
[image: playa relationships]

3) You can now use the parent entry to display the sub content. You'll of course need to pull all this data into your templates with something like the following:

```
<div id="right-side">
{exp:playa:children}

    {if channel_short_name == 'sidebar_javascript'}
        {cf_sidebar_js}
    {/if}

    {if channel_short_name == 'sidebar_videos'}
        {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}" embed_width="300" embed_height="238"}
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        {video:embed_code}
        <p class="caption">{video:title}</p>
        {/exp:channel_videos:videos}

    {/if}

    {if channel_short_name == 'sidebar_ads'}

     {exp:adman:show group="{cf_sidebar_adman_block}" order="RANDOM" limit="{cf_sidebar_adman_block_number_of}"}
         <a href="{ad_url}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{ad_image}" alt="{ad_alt}" />
         </a>
     {/exp:adman:show}    
    {/if}

{/exp:playa:children}
</div>
```

Comment: my drupal, php, linux, apache, postgresql, mysql encoded DNA won't allow me to buy a module for EE, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Seriously, paying for quality software that makes clients lives easier is sooooo overrated.

Answer (score 0):

We generally make a channel called something like "general content" with a single field that can have any kind of native formatting (none or xhtml would mostly be used) and then use it for one-off bits that don't fit into other channels.  It's hard for the client to find these entries in the CP for editing, so we make front-end "edit" links that open the correct entry in the CP and are visible only to member groups with content editing permissions.

This will only get hairy if you really need multiple customized fields for this use.

I have never used Low Variables, but I am under the impression that it could be useful here.

While I agree with the posters talking about the value of add-ons, this is a particular need that I have never had any problem solving natively.  Besides the issue of the cost of add-ons (which IMO is worthwhile) you also add complexity to your installation the more software you add to it, making it more time consuming to troubleshoot bugs and to upgrade EE.